# The localhost button in the phantom wallet is missing

Tags: phantom-wallet

The localhost button in the phantom wallet is missing Help pls
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qPDB.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the wallet to an older version and everything appeared again